# Console.log() inside a for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, console

I wonder what is the problem with my code below.
When I use `console.log(a[0])`, then the console shows me the first element of my array a. But, when i use `console.log(a[i])`, it does not really work. I expect in this case for `i = 0` the same value like when I use `console.log(a[0])`. Has it something to do with the push fucntion or where to locate the error?

Thx so much for your help!

```
var a = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

      a.push(b[i]);
    console.log(a[0]); // works
    console.log(a[i]); // doesn't work

    })
```

Comment: you syntax itself are wrong. can you paste exact snippet here which is not working

Comment: yeah, the error is, that `console.log(a[i]);`does not show up on the console.

Comment: It says `a[i] is undefined`

Comment: Apart from an extra parenth at the end of the snippet, and assuming `a` and `links` are populated and have equal length, [your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/j0awdg2r/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = []
for ( var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { <------------changed to b.length

  a.push(b[i]);
  console.log(a[i]); 

})
```

Comment: So in a way, you would need to push the iterator's value(s) into a new Array in order to console log it at the i index. 
This could be due to the fact that the b array is currently in use of the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some code. `links` and `b`, in particular.

```js
let a = [];
let b = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
let links = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  a.push(b[i]);
  //console.log(a[0]); // works
  console.log(a[i]); // also works
}
```